# GUI Uninstalled after installing fuse

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, 23.10

What action need to be taken if accidentally your ubuntu desktop got corrupted after installing any packages. for example:

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 23.10, I ran "sudo apt-get install fuse" and it uninstalled my GUI and it is not booting up.

Comment: I couldn't believe the installation of fuse would have caused this, but it's true: fuse is now provided by the `fuse3` package (so there is no need to `apt install fuse`), but since `fuse` breaks `fuse3`, `apt install fuse` will remove `fuse3` and through its dependencies everything upto `ubuntu-desktop` and `ubuntu-minimal`. Oops! Good catch and well done on the fix.

Comment: Future proofing:  when running `apt install` don't blindly say yes.  READ what it is going to remove first and say no occasionally!!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I have rebooted by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del and then selected "ubuntu recovery" mode and in root shell, I ran below commands.

1. sudo apt autoremove fuse
2. sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Note: instead of installing fuse, libfuse2 is greater for 22.04 and later version.

Comment: Good rescue! Instead of `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, which is a transitional package since Ubuntu 17.10, the preferred package to install now would be `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: @zwets That's Great, Thank you so much for replying and brightening the answer :)